# Extracting tabular data from multiple .xlsx files with inconsistent structures

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, yolo

I have multiple excel spreadsheets containing a range of data including tables. I need to access a particular table from every file. I considered using pandas skiprows, however the line at which the table is found in each sheet is variable, both from the start and the end of the sheet. In the example below, I need to access the last table with headers 'Well', 'Content' etc., and convert this to a dataframe to do something with. To be celar, in this example the row of the table in question is 115, however, this changes from file to file. Similarly, the distance from the end of the sheet is variable and inconsistent too. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

I have looked into openpyxl but didn't find anything which would isolate the table based on header values. I have also looked into pd.read_excel skiprows and/or indexing the dataframe using iloc. The issue here is the inconsistent position of the table, and variable size of the table.

Comment: Is the table named? If so you could access the `.ref` - like in the last example here: https://pbpython.com/pandas-excel-range.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by getting the index of the first row, and then the index of the nearest row below with a cell consistent to all files (in this case 'Basic Settings' is always the same distance away from the bottom of the table). As below:

```
#defining the header index by getting the first column heading
header_index = raw_table[raw_table[0].eq('Well')].index.values[0]
#defining the footer dimensions based on the first consistent title 
footer_index = raw_table[raw_table[0].eq('Basic settings')].index.values[0]
#Slicing the table according to the indices determined above, the footer is *strong text*3 
#below the end, so subtracting 3 
cropped_table = raw_table[header_index:footer_index-3]'''
```

Comment: As mentioned; The specified data does not appear to be a table however if the data was then Openpyxl would be able to reference it by name like **'Table3': 'A115:I187'** or similarly Pandas.